# Looping through a file to delete files from s3 - boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

This is probably very basic but I'm new to this so please bear with me!

I've been given a list of objects stored in s3 that need to be permanently deleted. This list is just a .txt file that I have no control over, but it does conveniently contain all of the specific keys that need to be removed e.g:

```
folder1/file1.xyz 
folder1/file2.xyz
folder2/file1.xyz
```

This is what I am trying which does not seem to actually delete the objects:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3bucket = "my bucket"
trn = "list.txt"

with open(trn) as trn_list:
    for line in trn_list:
         s3.delete_object(Bucket=s3bucket, Key=line)
```

If I specify a key to delete instead of looping through the file, it works and the object is removed, for example:

```
s3.delete_object(Bucket=s3bucket, Key=folder1/file1.xyz)
```

but when I try to include the delete into the loop it never seems to delete anything. If I run the loop to just *print(line)* then it correctly prints out each key in the .txt file.

Is there a different way I need to be doing this? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're looping over each line, the line will contain the newline in the string, so you need to remove it before using it as the key to a call into boto3:

```python
    for line in trn_list:
         s3.delete_object(Bucket=s3bucket, Key=line.strip())
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much for pointing this out! It was indeed including the newline which then didn't match up with a valid key in the bucket. Thanks again much appreciated!